# Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to an Intranet

Tags: asp.net, deployment, copy-paste

I have an ASP.NET web application that I just completed.  I am now preparing to deploy the application to my company's intranet.  I wanted to prepare the files so that I can simply give them to my company's IT group for uploading.  I reviewed some of the previous Q&As posted on this website; however, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to deploy an ASP.NET web application from Visual Studio.  From what I am finding, it looks like I have to go through the VS features to copy the files to a server.  Unfortunately, I built the web app on my personal computer so I do not have access to any of my company's internal servers.

Therefore, I was hoping there was a way to just gather the files from VS and then place them conveniently in a folder to be copied into a server, such as IIS.  Sort of like deploying a C# application by simply copying the install files to a computer.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

For additional information, I am using VS 2008 and the web app reads off of an Access Db through ADO.NET (I understand I will have to change the path before deployment).

Thank you,

Damion

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you are using a Web Application Project.  Right click on your web project in Visual Studio and select Publish.  You can publish to a local folder on your file system, and then provide those files to your company's IT group.  Be sure you select the "only files needed to run this application" option.  Is your Access file in your App_Data folder or elsewhere on your network?

Comment: Thanks Mike - That's a great question.  Currently, I have been using a test Db on the same drive as my web app (on my PC); however, I did not know if the real Db (tables) had to sit in the same folder as the web app or if the Db could sit on another drive.  I was going to just change the ADO.NET drive path.  In your opinion, where would you recommend that I place the Db?

Thanks again,

Comment: @DFM - I would seriously consider using SQL Server instead of Access.  SQL Server Express Edition is free and is more scalable than Access.  I am an Access-hater though, so I am biased.

Answer (score 0):

Yes- copying the Web app is fairly normal. I often do it this way. You can still do this with the publish tool- simple publish locally- e.g. a different folder on C:\ (you might want to deploy only the files needed to run the application) and then copy the files to the server/drop location for the IT team.

ASP.NET has always [supported XCopy deployment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326355).

Comment: Thanks Richard - As mentioned to the other repondents, I will most likely use the Publish feature.  However, I noticed that you mentioned I can publish to another local folder.  After I do that, will I be able to upload that folder to any web server that is able to read the application?

Thank you again,

Comment: Yes you will be able to do that. You could even test the locally deployed copy if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Publish feature to publish to a server that you have access to and instruct the IT group to copy it from there

Comment: Thanks Cody - I will use the Publish feature; it seems that this is the consensus.  Currently, I don't have access to the server.  Will the Publish feature let me save the files in an arbitrary folder that my IT group can copy the files from?  This way I can just transfer the files to them through a thumb drive.  If not, I can probably VPN to a server, but that may be a logistic nightmare.

Thanks again,

Comment: @DFM - You can publish the files wherever you want.  Publish it to a local dummy folder on your machine and you can do what you want with it (copy and paste elsewhere, zip and email, etc.).